# Why does range(index(x)) inside rollapply behave differently to outside (and just for my articifial data!)

Tags: r, xts

I was about to blog about a useful R function I'd made, went to create some dummy data, but the dummy data behaves differently! Help!

```
 library(xts)
 data=xts(1:139,Sys.Date()-139:1)
```

Looking at it, it all looks good:

```
> head(data)
           [,1]
2012-03-07    1
2012-03-08    2
2012-03-09    3
2012-03-10    4
2012-03-11    5
2012-03-12    6
> tail(data)
           [,1]
2012-07-18  134
2012-07-19  135
2012-07-20  136
2012-07-21  137
2012-07-22  138
2012-07-23  139
> head(index(data))
[1] "2012-03-07" "2012-03-08" "2012-03-09" "2012-03-10" "2012-03-11" "2012-03-12"
> tail(index(data))
[1] "2012-07-18" "2012-07-19" "2012-07-20" "2012-07-21" "2012-07-22" "2012-07-23"
> range(index(data))
[1] "2012-03-07" "2012-07-23"
```

But, rollapply is weird. The `range(index())` gives "1 40" instead of the strings.

```
> rollapply(data,width=40,by=30,FUN=function(x){print(range(index(x)));length(x)})
[1]  1 40
[1]  1 40
[1]  1 40
[1]  1 40

2012-03-26 40
2012-04-25 40
2012-05-25 40
2012-06-24 40
```

This is officially *weird*, because on my *real* data rollapply outputs a date range as strings. Comparing `str` on my real data and the above artificial data, and they are identical. In particular they both say '*Indexed by objects of class: [Date] TZ:*' and they both say: '*tclass: chr "Date"*'

Well, no, I exaggerate; the following artificial data has identical structure to my real data:

```
data=xts(data.frame(a=1:139,b=seq(3.14,by=0.01,length.out=139)),Sys.Date()-139:1)
```

It has exactly the same weird rollapply issue.

P.S. The useful function I mentioned is a rollapply wrapper; I've not shown it above because I don't need to: the core xts rollapply shows the problem too. But I'll post a link to it, in a comment, when I finally blog about it :-)

---

**UPDATE**

Here is some output with an xts object where it works:

```
> rollapply(data,width=40,by=30,FUN=function(x){print(class(x));print(range(index(x)));length(x)})
[1] "xts" "zoo"
[1] "2012-01-02" "2012-02-24"
...
> class(data)
[1] "xts" "zoo"
> str(data)
An ‘xts’ object from 2012-01-02 to 2012-07-18 containing:
  Data: num [1:139, 1] 76.9 76.7 76.7 77.1 76.9 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr "Close"
  Indexed by objects of class: [Date] TZ: 
  xts Attributes:  
List of 2
 $ tclass: chr "Date"
 $ tzone : chr ""
```

Here is some output with my artificial xts object (except I've added: `colnames(data)=c("Close")`)

```
> rollapply(data,width=40,by=30,FUN=function(x){print(class(x));print(range(index(x)));length(x)})
[1] "integer"
[1]  1 40
...
> class(data)
[1] "xts" "zoo"
> str(data)
An ‘xts’ object from 2012-03-07 to 2012-07-23 containing:
  Data: int [1:139, 1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr "Close"
  Indexed by objects of class: [Date] TZ: 
  xts Attributes:  
List of 2
 $ tclass: chr "Date"
 $ tzone : chr ""
```

I.e. identical str/class, identical function call, but different result. The xts object where it works is read from a csv file using this code:

```
d=read.table(fname,sep=',',header=T,stringsAsFactors=F)
x=as.xts(subset(d,select=-datestamp),order.by=as.Date(d$datestamp))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe the following:

```
rollapply(data,width=40,by=30,FUN=function(x){class(x)}) 

2012-03-26 integer
2012-04-25 integer
2012-05-25 integer
2012-06-24 integer
```

`rollapply` is passing the subsets of data as `integer` rather than `xts` objects.

The code for `zoo:::rollapply.zoo` appears to only use standard `[` subsetting so it's not clear why the class information is being lost.

**Edit**

Actually there is a line:

```
dat <- mapply(f, seq_along(time(data)), width, MoreArgs = list(data = coredata(data), 
    ...), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

So only the `coredata` is being passed to the eventual function. This means you can't use `rollapply` to get these partial ranges.

Comment: Thanks. That looks like a useful clue. The code where it works fine I see `"xts" "zoo"` for the class, and where it doesn't I see "integer" (or "numeric") (See the update I just added to the question.)

Comment: BTW, the code being used is `xts:::rollapply.xts` (or I've misunderstood the R object model yet again :-)

Comment: @DarrenCook: `xts:::rollapply.xts` is not exported or registered as a S3 method, so it's not being used.

Comment: @DarrenCook `xts:::rollapply.xts` does appear to give the output you want, so you could just use that explicitly. It is still a mystery why it works with one and not the other though...

Comment: @James Aha! I just realized I'd been running my artificial example in a fresh R session: when I try in same session as the real data it works... about to investigate why!

Comment: Got it! `library(PerformanceAnalytics)` and it behaves the way I expected. This is before or after `library(xts)`. Based on Joshua's comment that implies PerformanceAnalytics is registering `xts:::rollapply.xts` as an S3 method, whereas xts itself doesn't??

Comment: @DarrenCook: that may be it.  I wrote `xts:::rollapply.xts` at the PerformanceAnalytics authors' request.  Documenting, exporting, and registering it have been on my to-do list for awhile... just ask Brian. ;-)

Comment: @DarrenCook, Look at zzz.R in PerformanceAnalytics.  They do this `rollapply.xts <- xts:::rollapply.xts`. Also look at the rest of that file because it has caused me headaches in the past (i.e. defining xts and matrix methods for base generics which is, IMHO, awful programming practice).

Comment: Note that in the development version of the zoo package that `rollapply.zoo` has an argument `coredata=FALSE` which will cause a zoo object to be passed and not just the coredata.